# Are these termites?

Tags: entomology, species-identification

These are outside a window in Phoenix, Arizona. I looked on the internet for pictures and these guys looked very similar to winged termites.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have any shots from above?

Comment: @Oreotrephes no, unfortunately not, they're just sitting on the glass

Comment: Based on the pinched waist, I'd say these are [hymenopterans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hymenoptera), not termites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They could be halictid bees, possibly *Agapostemon splendens*.

Yours looks very similar to this picture

[image: CC by 2.0 by Bob Peterson]

[(by Bob Peterson)](https://www.flickr.com/photos/pondapple/9962435963/in/photolist-gbm68i-4UTbZp-ozM511-6XPoeR-9DJ4HH-okaBM1-fb4yAr-aobyMZ-o6YfJb-vzDkuE-r36DPi-fb4yRk-fbiPoS-fbiPhU-5rU9Pd-6zDB7g-tksqre-sSKDsj-tam6ya-6Rbojh-t3PMzq-vss6nJ-tksygn-avN3hU-4YiWbe-enJ5DK-6VQqMs-6VDyzJ-tk8n1A-8ytLy4-taoy7c-drSYgg-afSau7-obHu8C-acJa4C-gSGrGL-eXRH35-nEupa-soo5JQ-smkWjs-mDvwnD-vPngwm-gkSfp2-gkSrX3-gkS5Rd-33UefA-obDmbL-rGi7uC-7eDps6-pxEvuh)

Compare also with this one [on bugguide](http://bugguide.net/node/view/155774) and to the pictures of *Agapostemon* species in [this National Geographic article](http://voices.nationalgeographic.com/2014/10/24/hair-bands-and-giant-trousers-a-lesson-in-how-little-i-know-about-bees/).

Compare the metallic head and thorax (that's the middle segment), the striped abdomen (the last segment), the apparent large size of eyes and place of antennae attachment, and the 'buff' hindlegs.